# Disable entire view tree

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-view, android-xml

I am trying to display a view over another view in my layout and at the same time disable the view that is in the back...

Here are some screenshots to better understand my request:

[image: Here is the first view]

[image: and the semitransparent view that goes over the top.]

Problem is i can still click on the edit text fields in the back view.

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_body"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kitu_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/login_logo_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/login_logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontEditText
            android:id="@+id/email_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/white_shape_border"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="@dimen/edit_text_padding" />

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/white_shape_no_top_border"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="@dimen/edit_text_padding" />

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontButton
            android:id="@+id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_white_selector"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontButton
        android:id="@+id/register_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_register_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="@color/register_text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/loading_backgroud"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yellow_wheel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:src="@drawable/loading_yellow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/incorrect_email_password_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/loading_backgroud"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/noInternetConnection"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ro.gebs.kitu.ui.custom.views.CustomFontButton
            android:id="@+id/dismiss_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_message"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_dismiss_btn"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here i try to disable the back view:

```
parentLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

where `parentLayout` is initialized here:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view;
        initView(view);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use view.setEnabled(false). You can just set a onTouchListener to the upper layer cover, and in the callback function of onTouch method, always return true.

In this case, your touch event will not "fall back" to the view behind.